# How to connect oracle database(Server_A) via Linux Machine(Server_B) through shell script?

Tags: linux, oracle, shell

I have a concern I want to connect oracle database(It is running in Server_A) through shell script(script is running Server_B).I have a following informations to connect oracle database.

1) server name(I don't have password)
2) schema name
3) SID
3) database name
4) table name

Comment: Please add some example what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only know the given parameters (host, sid/databasename, tablename) you also should ask for a user within the database which is able to connect to it and query the given table name.

You then also have to install something like the **oracle-instantclient-sqlplus** to execute the **sqlplus** command. If you want to use the database connection with another language like Perl, Python or Ruby you will have to dig a lot deeper to find native connectors. Using the **sqlplus** command there as well is also possible. See [this link](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus) for the usage of **sqlplus**.

To connect to the database, you most probably also have to create a **/etc/tnsnames.ora** file which will map your connection-string to a host/database combination. See [this link](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora) for further details.